# Google Cloud LAMP VM, SSL issue

Tags: ssl, https, lamp

I'm trying to add an SSL certificate to a site on a LAMP VM on Google Cloud.
I've generated a certificate from https://www.sslforfree.com/.

Non SSL version of the site is running okay, and I have added SSL mod to Apache and can start Apache with:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /home/info/pub

  <Directory /home/info/pub>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /home/info/ssl/se.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/info/ssl/se.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /home/info/ssl/se.ca
</VirtualHost>
```

Under Networking in the Cloud panel i see the following:
lamp-1-tcp-443 Ingress  lamp-1-tcp-443  IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 tcp:443 Allow 1000

Although when try and access the https:// version of the website, firefox responds with (removed URLs from the copy/paste):
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to [URL omitted]. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Same thing happens in Chromium:
This site can’t provide a secure connection

[URL omitted] sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I really don't know what might be causing this.

Comment: Instead of trying to add the 443 config to the standard site config for apache, I've gone ahead and configured the same options in default-ssl conf file. After restarting https seems to work fine, but although I have the config pointed to the same directory as in the standard default lamp server conf apache now gives me 403 forbidden when trying to access the https site. Not sure why this would be forbidden seeing how the non https connection works fine and does not produce 403 error.

Comment: The config file for default ssl also needs the <Directory tags. This solved the 403 issue.